# Automating Jenkins module install

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Is there any way to automate the install of modules within Jenkins? I'm trying to script/automate the install of my CI box as much as possible. I have just about everything working but at the moment it requires someone go into Jenkins and install the modules via the web interface.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the plugins from http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/PLUGIN_NAME/latest/PLUGIN_NAME.hpi . Dropping them into jenkins/plugins/ will do the trick.

Don't forget to restart Jenkins.

Also, if you're using Chef instead of Puppet, the Jenkins cookbook will take care of installing plugins as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [puppet-jenkins](https://github.com/rtyler/puppet-jenkins) module automates the entire process of the Jenkins installation through [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet/). It also has manifests for installing plugins, either by specifying a version you want or by installing the latest version.

If you do not already use Puppet and do not want to implement this module in your system, you can take a look at the [plugin manifest](https://github.com/rtyler/puppet-jenkins/blob/master/manifests/plugin.pp) and see how the process of plugins was automated.